# Export 3 GridViews to the same worksheet in Excel in ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I am trying to figure out how to export my GridView1, GridView2, and GridView3 to Excel document, so all of those GridViews would be on the same worksheet.

I have a code that allows me to export just one of my GridViews:

Here is my C# button_Click event code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ClosedXML;
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using System.IO;


public partial class Page1 : System.Web.UI.Page

{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 

    }  

    protected void btnExportData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string style = @"<style> .text { mso-number-format:\@; } </style> ";
            Response.ClearContent();

            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcelFile.xls");

            Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            GridView1.RenderControl(htw);

            // Style is added dynamically

            Response.Write(style);

            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();

        }
  }
```

If you have any idea on how to get those 3 GridViews exported to the Excel worksheet, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: `GridView1.RenderControl(htw); GridView2.RenderControl(htw); GridView3.RenderControl(htw); ` ?

Comment: That worked! Do you know how to add a space in between of the gridviews by any chance? Or how to add a Title text? Thanks!

Comment: you're just writing HTML, just throw a <br /> in between